# Single category's posts list in admin menu

Tags: admin, admin-menu

the "authors" in my site should only be allowed to add/edit posts in a single category (i.e.:News). I am preparing the backend for them and I would like to remove the "Posts" menu and show in its place a "News" menu, from which the authors could only list and add/edit the posts in that Category.

No problem to remove the menu items in admin menu, but how can I reach my target to show posts only for the news category?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a custom post type "News" and hide the menu item of "posts" - The code below will create a Custom post type for news

```
/*
* Creating a function to create our CPT
*/

function custom_post_type() {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'News', 'Post Type General Name', 'texdomain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'News', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'texdomain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'News', 'texdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent News', 'texdomain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All News', 'texdomain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View News', 'texdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New News', 'texdomain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'texdomain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit News', 'texdomain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update News', 'texdomain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search News', 'texdomain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'texdomain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'texdomain' 
  ),
);

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'News', 'texdomain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'News news and reviews', 'texdomain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,

// Features this CPT supports in Post Editor

    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),

// You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 

    'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
    /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
    * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
    * is like Posts.
    */  
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
   );

 // Registering your Custom Post Type
register_post_type( 'News', $args );

}

/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not 
* unnecessarily executed. 
*/

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

In order to hide the post menu item from Authors the easy way is using this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/ 
or you can do it with custom functions, more info on this site https://www.wpmayor.com/how-to-remove-menu-items-in-admin-depending-on-user-role/